# How do I send data to a Rails controller from Flex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex

I am trying to use an HTTPService to send a string of text to a controller action. How do I access it within the controller? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any parameters you send should be accessible from the params hash in the controller. For example, if I pass a Rails application the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/search?q=articles
```

I will be able to access the value like this:

```
#in articles_controller.rb    
def search
  query = params[:q]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to integrate Flex with Rails is to use [RubyAMF](http://blog.rubyamf.org/about/) ( http://code.google.com/p/rubyamf/ ).

Comment: I was hoping I would be able to do something a little more native and simpler. But, thanks.